# Find closest number as exponent datatype

Tags: c#, math, types

I have a datatype A which looks like this:

```
struct A {
    byte addBase;
    byte addExponent;
    byte subBase;
    byte subExponent;
}
```

The value of A is calculated as (addBase^addExponent - subBase^subExponent). What I am trying to do is find the closest match for a number between 0 and 255^255 but the only idea I have would be to brute force the closets match, which would be really slow.

Comment: I don't think you quite grasp the size of the numbers you're talking about... 255^255 is well over 600 digits long in decimal. the number of subatomic particles in the universe is only somewhere around 80 digits long. What do you need a number that size for?

Comment: I know these numbers are are really big but it is more of an theoretical thing I wanted to use for my toy compression. Since a byte can hold 0 to 255, this is the range I use.

Comment: I wouldn't really recommend using such a basic datatype as a byte for math, because it will require casting into the right format more often than not. Also, there's another Stack Exchange sistersite (a couple, actually) focused on math that can help you find better solutions fast. This problem isn't new and there should be several algorithms with better performance than a bruteforce tactic.